# How to destructure redux state in react redux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am not getting the point of using `...`in `...state`. When I have watched a tutorial of react redux they mentioned that it is destructuring of state variable but can you explain me the point mentioned .

```
export const productreducer=(state=initialstate,{type,payload})=>{

switch(type)
 case ActionTypes.SETPRODUCTS:
     return{...state,...payload}; //here I have a doubt
 default:
     return state
}
};
```

Comment: The spread `...` syntax makes it easy to override and add new properties with removing existing ones. It also creates a new object so `oldState !== newState` but `oldState['unchange'] === newState['unchanged']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So {...} refers to spread or expand out the iterable elements, Lets take an example, you cannot change the state directly in the redux store and therefore you need to make a copy and append the new payload to the state and return the state.

state={ x:1, y:2 }
payload={ y:5 , z:6 }

{...state, ...payload} // *{ x: 1, y: 5, z: 6 }*

This will update the old state to the new state.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, assume you have

```
const a = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
```

then the following two are equivalent:

```
return { foo: a.foo, bar: b.bar }
```

and

```
return { ...a }
```

so essentially, `...` copies over all the elements from the old object into a new object.

That said, modern Redux doesn't do this. Modern Redux also does not do switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES or connect. You might have been following a very outdated tutorial.

I would really recommend you to follow the official [Redux Essentials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) tutorial that will teach you modern Redux from the beginning - it's much safer against accidental errors and only a fourth of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It's [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). In your case, it gets all key: value pairs from objects and combines them into a new object. Hope with snippet it will be more clear

```js
const state = {a: 1, b: 2}
const payload = {c: 3, d: 4}

const result = {...state, ...payload}
console.log(result)
```